# Mapview zoom controls not shown if i override onTouchEvent method

Tags: java, android, android-mapview

I override onTouchEvent so i can detect where on the map was clicked. But now my zoom controls have disappeared. My onTouchEvent:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) {

          final int action=event.getAction();
          final int x=(int)event.getX();
          final int y=(int)event.getY();
          boolean result=false;


          if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) { 
              //Log.d(TAG, "down");      
              result=true;

          }
           if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

             //Log.d(TAG, "move");           
            result=true;
          }
          else if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) { 


            GeoPoint pt=mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(x,
                                                       y);

            OverlayItem toDrop=new OverlayItem(pt, "MyLoc","Tukaj me poberite");

            locations.clear();
            locations.add(toDrop); 
            populate();

            result=true;
          }

           return(result || super.onTouchEvent(event, mapView));
        }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I also found out that map cant be moved.

Answer (score 1):

You have to alway call

```
super.onTouchEvent(event, mapView));
```

to make Mapview run normally.
So the last line of your code

```
return(result || super.onTouchEvent(event, mapView));
```

should be changed to

```
super.onTouchEvent(event, mapView);
return true;
```